# docker port mapping for consul agent

Tags: docker, mapping, port, consul

I just downloaded a the consul 0.6.3  in linux machine and warpped it up in a docker container. In the container i am running the command

```
consul agent -dev
```

It runs perfectly and inside the container if i do

```
$ curl localhost:8500/v1/catalog/nodes
```

the output is

```
[{"Node":"8f1841ad54bb","Address":"172.17.0.163","CreateIndex":3,"ModifyIndex":4}]
```

which is perfect.

Now in the mother machine where docker daemon is running if i do `docker ps` it shows the correct running container

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE        COMMAND               STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
8f1841ad54bb        myconsul   "/bin/bash"           Up 35 minutes       0.0.0.0:32787->8500/tcp   consul-server
```

However if from the mother machine i do a

```
# curl localhost:32787/v1/catalog/nodes
```

It says

```
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Though the docker mapping seems to be correct, can anyone tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you try adding `-client=0.0.0.0` while starting consul so that it will accept for all client requests

Comment: I did that and it throws an error while starting consul stating Failed to parse IP 0.0.0.0

Comment: Seems to be a weird error as ip 0.0.0.0 is valid . Can you please post the startup logs / error here ?

Comment: Usual reason for this is a `localhost` port binding, which doesn't work with `-p`